# Odoo domain filter POS many2many

Tags: javascript, filter, many-to-many, odoo-8, point-of-sale

I'd like to add a domain filter on the res.users model in the Odoo POS.
I want to base this filter on the user group, this is a many2many field so any ideas how I can achieve this. I tried following without result.

```
  {
      model:  'res.users',
      fields: ['name','ean13'],
      domain: [['groups_id.gid','=',52]],
      loaded: function(self,users){ self.users = users; },
  },
```

Comment: Try  `[('groups_id.gid','in',[52])]`

Comment: same error: Invalid field 'gid' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('gid', 'in', [52]) on res_groups (ctx: )>